# Http response 401 accessing service behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a spring boot application hosting restful services that sits behind an Nginx reverse proxy. The Nginx configuration lets accepts requests on http://mynginx/proxy/ and proxies them transparently to http://host/service/. The target service is secured and requires the Oauth token in the Authorization header. When I call the service directly using GET http://host/service it works as expected however. The same with different destination GET http://mynginx/proxy gives a 401 unauthorized HTTP response. 
I ultimately want to lock down my application so it is not publicly accessible so do not want to expose the target service directly. What do I need to do to get Authorization working through Nginx?

Here is my Nginx configuration for this service call

```
        location /proxy/ {
          proxy_pass http://host/service/;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";  
          proxy_set_header   Authorization $http_authorization;
          proxy_pass_header  Authorization;   
        }
```